# Wheels of the car sinking on ground plane

Tags: game-engine

I'm trying to make a drivable car.  I made the  floor a rigid body passive. The wheels are either convex hull or cylinder and the scale is applied (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).

When I press play in the blender game, the wheels sink into the plane.

I made one cube and 4 wheels and I get the same result.

I parented wheels ,child, to the car. Car its rigid body, no sleeping convex hull. Wheels are not collision, plane its static.

What am I missing?

[image: test]

Comment: Have you tried to enable the physics visualization to see what's going on? Maybe the wheels aren't in the correct collision shape or radius.

Comment: ty for you ansver  not help mi . ,I do not know how to put the  blender file here ..so mi email its crypes@live.com if its ok for you

Comment: Upload blend files on this site: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ , edit your question and post the generated link on it. Delete your email from your comment, as it could bring spam to you.

Comment: i can t upload they tell mi error uploading ,i try more time...no way working

Comment: ok I've done this with python script from this tutorial,,,How to add vehicle suspension in the blender game engine (HD)...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB23rVp6IQ4...............in python you need to increase radius

Comment: @crype but this tutorial is for blender 2.6, the API blender is very different for 2.79